# Cron Job in Fedora 8 - Not getting the desired result

Tags: cron, cron-task

OS   : Fedora release 8 
user : root

**crontab -e :output**

```
11 * * * * root /bin/touch /home/arun/Desktop/f1
```

But this cron job is not creating new file 'f1'.

**/var/log/cron :says**

```
Feb 21 09:11:01 localhost CROND[5762]: (root) CMD (root /bin/touch /home/arun/Desktop/f1 )
```

In command line I executed below command and it creates file f1.

```
#/bin/touch /home/arun/Desktop/f1
```

Comment: **8**? Holy cow, that's old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute the command `root /bin/touch /home/arun/Desktop/f1`
The executable 'root' obviously does not exist. Try removing 'root' (via crontab -e) and make the crontab entry look like:

```
 11 * * * * /bin/touch /home/arun/Desktop/f1
```

Comment: Yes it Worked .. Thanks a lot 'wildplasser' . I was really stuck in this issue .. Thanks one again